# Get maximum interval between two consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript

i need to get the maximum interval between two consecutive numbers. Numbers are entered as arguments. Wrote some solution, but don't know how to move on. How can this problem be solved?

```js
const maxInterv = (...args) => {
  let maxInterval = 0;
  let interval = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    interval = args[i + 1] - args[i];

  }
};

const result = maxInterv(3, 5, 2, 7, 11, 0, -2); //11

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You didn't return anything from the function

Comment: [This](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/intervals.html) is the math behind intervals. Check out the "All Three Methods Together" section and implement in the for loop. Also, as @caTS stated, return `interval` from the function

Comment: (also this is a *range*, not an interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const maxInterv = (...args) => {
  // moved interval to the loop, because you don't use that here
  let maxInterval = 0;
  // you are accessing i + 1 so you have to iterate to args.length - 1
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
    // use abs or you will get negative values
    const interval = Math.abs(args[i + 1] - args[i]);
    // if current interval is greater than max, set new max
    if (interval > maxInterval) {
      maxInterval = interval
    }
  }
  // remember to return
  return maxInterval
};

const result = maxInterv(3, 5, 2, 7, 11, 0, -2);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const maxInterval = (...args) => {
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 1, interval = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    interval = args[i - 1] - args[i];
    if (Math.abs(interval) > max) max = interval;
  }
  return max;
};
const result = maxInterval(3, 5, 2, 7, 11, 0, -2); //11
console.log("the result is", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple `array.reduce()`

```js
const maxInterv = (...args) => 
  args.reduce( (intv,val,i,{[i+1]:nxt}) =>
    !isNaN(nxt) ? Math.max(intv,Math.abs(val-nxt)) : intv
    ,0);
 
const result = maxInterv(3, 5, 2, 7, 11, 0, -2); // 11
                      
document.write( result )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the shortest one=)

```js
const maxInterv = (arr) => Math.max(...arr.slice(1).map(
  (val, key) => Math.abs(val - arr[key])));

const result = maxInterv([3, 5, 2, 7, 11, 0, -2]); // 11

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `maxInterval` with `-Infinity` and use `Math.max()` and `Math.abs()` function in each interation. Pay attention to range of `i`.

On the end return `maxInterval` variable.